# Put company logo in cf7 plugin message body

Tags: wordpress

I'm using contact form 7 plugin on wordpress. Just want to add a company logo in message body, but no success it doesn't understand img tag at all. Tried to put src value in {} brackets but no result.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
1. Check Use HTML content type box in the Mail or Mail (2) section.
2. Place <img src="url_path" /> tag into the Message body textarea.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just checked the checkbox(Use HTML content type). And works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As Jenis said, you must check "Use HTML" in Mail Section.
Then, img url must have full path, not relative path in order to work.

Example: `<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" />`

You can also specify the width inline or make a header title in message body an H3 Tag. All HTML tags are working fine!

**WORKING AT 2023**